# Android Junit test with mockito

Tags: android, junit, mockito, junit4

Is my unit test code is correct?

**LoginFragmentViewModel.java**

```
private final LoginRepository mLoginRepository;
    MutableLiveData<String> mLoginResponseLiveData;    

    public LoginFragmentViewModel() {
        mLoginRepository = new LoginRepository();
    }

    public LiveData<String> doLogin(String username, String password) {
        mLoginResponseLiveData = mLoginRepository.login(username, password);
        return mLoginResponseLiveData;
    }
```

**LoginFragmentViewModelTest.java**

```
@Test
public void check_do_login(){
        LoginRepository loginRepository = mock(LoginRepository.class);
        MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData = mock(MutableLiveData.class);
        mutableLiveData.setValue("Testing value");
        when(loginRepository.login(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mutableLiveData);

        LiveData<String> stringLiveData = mLoginFragmentViewModel.doLogin("username@gmail.com", "password@123");
        assertEquals(stringLiveData.getValue(),"Testing value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting mocking *wrong*:

```
MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData = mock(MutableLiveData.class);
mutableLiveData.setValue("Testing value");
```

That first line creates a **mock** object. This object has *nothing* to do with the real implementation. Therefore your second call is **pointless**!

You need a mock specification instead; like for the other mock:

```
when(mutableLiveData.getValue()).thenReturn("Testing value");
```

But the question is: are you sure that you have to create a **mocked** instance of MutableLiveData?

You see - even when you fix that problem I outlined - your test is doing nothing else but "re-implementing" the production code. Yes, the test tests that production code, but as soon as you change your production code, chances are that your test will break.

Long story short:

- consider if you really need to mock `mutableLiveData`
- maybe your class under test is simply "too small". You want to focus on the public contract of methods for testing; but the contract of your production code is pretty ... small.

Comment: my first doubt is shall we need to unit test simple methods like doLogin in Viewmodel class.It just contains forwarding code to repository.Second,shall I test login method(of Repository class) from same test without mocking it..is it good practice or I should test Repository class method separately?